# c++ equivalent to python append method for lists

Tags: c++, python, arrays, list, std

I'm learning c++ coming from a background in python.

I'm wondering is there a way to append items to a list in c++?

```
myList = []
for i in range(10):
    myList.append(i)
```

Is there something like this in c++ that you can do to an array?

Comment: Do you mean a vector, a list, or an array?

Comment: You probably want the `myList=[]` before the loop. Otherwise you're clearing it every iteration and will end up with `myList=[9]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a vector, do something like this:

```
#include <vector>

void funct() {
    std::vector<int> myList;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        myList.push_back(10);
}
```

See http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/ for more information.

Comment: Having to remember how to do this in C++ has made me realize how spoiled I've become with python. Anyway, what's nice about vector is how you can still use brackets to access items: `myList[9] == 9`.

Answer (score 2):

For list Use **[std::list::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/push_back/)**

If you are looking for a array equivalent of C++, You should use **[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)**
vector also has a **[std::vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/)** method

Answer (score 1):

You should use vector:

```
vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    v.push_back(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `std::vector`, there's a `push_back` method that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Lists have the push_back method.

```
myList.push_back(myElement);
```

It pushes myElement onto the end of myList.
Same as Python's list.append.